# How to Remove special character "/" from a 2D array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D Array which contains special characters '/'. I just want to get rid of it without affecting other values including blank field.

my array looks like `array = [['S1/L','S1/F',''],['S2/F','' ,'S3/F'],['MS/F','S1/H','S3/L']]`

I want the result as `Result_array = [['S1L','S1F','' ],['S2F','' ,'S3F'],['MSF','S1H','S3L']].`

I did not find any matching answer to this question that I can refer to that is why I am posting it here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Is the `/` you want to remove part of a string, the values you posted look like a division, example, the first value is the result of dividing the two variables `S1` and `L`, if you remove `/` it becomes `S1L`, do you have a variable called `S1L`? Or are these all strings? Please clarify.

Comment: The code you posted does not seem it's a valid javascript code. Either the array items are strings, then quotes are missing, or they are expressions and slash is a division sign.

Comment: no Its just a string `'S1/L'`. Please dont be confuse.

Comment: This code won't even work in the first place because it should be in double quotes.

Comment: @Mask please update the question if all of those are strings, it's confusing at its current state.

Comment: I just edited my question. I am sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming it is a string array of arrays.

this code works

```
array = [["S1/L","S1/F", ""],["S2/F","" ,"S3/F"],["MS/F","S1/H","S3/L"]]

var newArr = array.map((arr)=>{
  return arr.map((ar)=>{
   return ar.replace("/","");
 });
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Note that `ar.replace("/", "")` replaces only first occurence of the slash.

Comment: True @Nytmo, if that's the case then replace that line with ```return ar.replace(/\//g,"");``` your answer helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is in place replacement:

```
for (var i in array)
    for (var j in array[i])
        array[i][j] = array[i][j].replace(/\//g, '');
```